# No known class method for selector canReadCardWithCamera

Tags: ios, card.io

Has anyone tried pulling the recent open card.io ios sources into your project ?
I am trying to add the card.io ios source project in my xcode project workspace. After successfully adding the "Link Binary With Libraries" and giving the header search path it still complaining me that it cannot find one of its class method. Or kindly guide If am still missing any step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dave from card.io here.

Amit, things changed a bit in card.io version 4.0.0. See the [release notes](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-iOS-SDK/blob/master/release_notes.txt) for all the details.

In particular, note this section:

`* New class: CardIOUtilities
  - libraryVersion         (formerly a method of CardIOPaymentViewController)
  - canReadCardWithCamera  (formerly a method of CardIOPaymentViewController)
  - preload                (formerly a method of CardIOView and of CardIOPaymentViewController)`